# PrimeFaces dialog doesn't show up programmatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I've been working with PrimeFaces library and the dialog API doesn't work on my browser.I'm using IntelliJ IDE and here is my sample:

index.xhtml

```
<h:body>
<h:form var="mainForm" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
  <p:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
  <h:outputLabel value="Please enter a name:"/>
  <p:inputText id="name" value="#{index.name}"/>
   <p:commandButton id="mButton" value="Submit" actionListener="#{index.buttonAction}" />
  </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

Index.class

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name="index")
public class Index implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public void buttonAction(){
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        List<String> paramValue = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String,List<String>> params = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
        Map<String,Object> options =  new HashMap<String,Object>();
        options.put("height",200);
        options.put("width",200);
        options.put("contentWidth",200);
        options.put("contentHeight",200);
        paramValue.add(name);
        params.put("requestKey",paramValue);
        requestContext.openDialog("popup",options,params);
    }
}
```

Under the directory "web" there are "popup.xhtml" and "index.html".

I have looked up other posts but none of them worked for me. What might be wrong?

Comment: One thing that is wrong is that you did not post what questions you tried as is requested in [ask] and `form var=...` weird usage

Comment: try to replace `requestContext.openDialog("popup",options,params);` by `requestContext.execute("PF('myDialogVar').show();");`